# decoding json with php - get url from Facebook profile pic

Tags: php, json, facebook-graph-api

I need to decode this json value using PHP. I need the value 'url'.

Here is what I have but does not work.

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/{fb-ID}/picture?type=large&redirect=false');

$decoded = json_decode($json,true);

$url = $decoded[???]; // NEED THIS VAR.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `$decoded` is a PHP array you can access it like any other array:

`$url = $decoded['data']['url'];`

Comment: Accidentally deleted it.. Glad I helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$decoded=(object)json_decode( $json['data'], true );
echo $decoded->url
```

Comment: This one didn't work. There was once answer but they deleted it but they were right. $decoded = json_decode($json,true);
$url = $decoded['data']['url']; // KId was right.

Comment: yeah sorry, should have tested it before posting it. 

$decoded=(object)json_decode( $json, true );
echo $decoded->data['url'];

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/{fb-ID}/picture?type=large&redirect=false');
$decoded = json_decode($json,true);
$url = $decoded['data']['url'];
```